# jqGrid - scrollbar appears in frozen column header

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

In my jqGrid table, the first column is a 'frozen' column and it is having a scroll bar in the header as shown below. If I remove the 'frozen' property, the scroll seems to disappear.

[image]

Code: See the 'frozen' property in first column

```
  colNames: [
                "Certification Name",
                "Current",
                "Lapsing",
                "Lapsed",
                "Not Certified",
                "Total Certification"
            ],
            colModel: [
                    { name: "CertificationName", index: "CertificationName", width: 550, frozen: true },
                    { name: "CurrentCount", index: "CurrentCount", width: 75, sorttype: "int", align: 'center' },
                    { name: "LappsingCount", index: "LappsingCount", width: 75, sorttype: "int", align: 'center' },
                    { name: "LappsedCount", index: "LappsedCount", width: 75, sorttype: "int", align: 'center' },
```

How do I remove the scroll bar or prevent the scroll bar from appearing in the first header column?

Note: I am using jqGrid plugin (version 4.6.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that the problem will be solved by the usage of

```css
ui-jqgrid > .ui-jqgrid-view > .ui-jqgrid-hdiv { overflow: hidden; }
```

By the way the CSS setting is included in [free jqGrid 4.8](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid).